# AJAX: Django's templates flexibility gone? Update CSS & JS?

Tags: ajax, django

Leaving all the header/footer/nav parts of pages untouched,
refreshing only page's content with AJAX,

can't use base template extension's block mechanism to set content-corresponding styles, scripts, page title?

Wonder how to get .css and .js for updated content with AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you will want to make all of your CSS and JS available in the header templates so that they are available when your dynamic content is loaded. The overhead is slight, and you will be following the "Django way."

Another option is to include inline CSS/JS in your dynamic content, but this approach is not recommended. It leads to messy code and can be difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: For now i've done things in everything_in_one_place manner, however recently one funny code snippet interested me on subj: `<script>
 (function () {
  var s = "script",
   n = '\n',
   d = document,
   b = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[2].innerHTML.split(n);
  d.write('<' + s + ' type="text/javascript" src="">' + b.slice(2, b.length - 2).join(n) + '</' + s + '>')
 })()
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Can't use full sentences?

Anyway, I have no idea why you think you need to get CSS and JS for partial pages. A set of HTML elements dynamically inserted via Ajax will simply use the existing CSS associated with the page.

Comment: Sorry for my english! Just trying to formulate my question as short and clear as I can, having no idea how it looks for native speaker :)

Answering your post: in my case, content and content's user interaction staff for each page individually is quite weirdly designed (the reason I have to use AJAX) and I suppose it's not right to link all the CSSs and JSs I have in one generic page simultaneously, abandoning individual content-dependant substitution.

Comment: ALL of css and js, i mean :)